# Cakephp 4 not running on Ubuntu 20.3

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, cakephp-4.x

After installing and creating a new CakePHP app using composer, I am trying to run the app on my browser using `bin/cake server`.

I get these errors:

> Warning: *cake_core* cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_eng' to File cache in /usr/share/php/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 327
>
> PHP Warning:  /usr/share/php/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /usr/share/php/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 389

Please can anyone help me with resolving these issues? I am new to Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to give the permission by command

sudo chmod -R 777 **FOLDERNAME**

Comment: Setting 777 is not a good idea. You should make sure that the user running the process that tries to write to the folder has access, not everyone.

Comment: try with 755 permission

Comment: I have tried the 777 permission, i am still getting the same error

Comment: I have tried both the 777 and 755 permissions, I still get the same errors